# How to prevent 'table is mark as and last (automatic) repair failed'?

Tags: mysql

This is the second time within the last 4 days that one of the tables in my database got corrupted. The is the error that I have seen in my apache log:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 144 Table [TABLE_NAME] is marked as crashed and last (automatic?) repair failed'

I managed to repair it manually using:

```
myisamchk -r -f $TABLE_NAME
```

but of course this is not a long term solution.

I need to understand why is this happening, so I can prevent it from happening again in the future.

- Total database size is 2Gb, 100 tables, 7.5 million rows.
- The table where it happened is the largest in the database: 1.2 million rows, 650Mb.
- Server version: 5.5.50
- ubuntu 14.04.1
- PHP 5.5.9
- I checked and there was enough free disk space. About ram, it was not an issue so far.
- The host where the db reside is c3.xlarge (8Gb ram)

The database sits in the server harddisk. I am thinking about moving it to RDS, I wonder if that would help.

What do you suggest I should do? Any way to analyze mysql and understand where is the problem?

### UPDATE

/var/log/mysql/error.log has this in it:

```
200213 14:57:21 [Warning] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Forcing close of thread 200315105  user: '[user1]'
200213 14:57:47 [Warning] Warning: Optimize table got errno 28 on [TABLENAME], retrying
200213 14:57:47  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200213 14:57:49  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1983956605556
```

## UPDATE - It is out of memory

found this in my syslog

```
Feb 16 11:18:16 ip-172-31-100-71 kernel: [67744017.270767] Out of memory: Kill process 14232 (mysqld) score 32 or sacrifice child
Feb 16 11:18:16 ip-172-31-100-71 kernel: [67744017.285148] Killed process 14232 (mysqld) total-vm:2447868kB, anon-rss:241432kB, file-rss:0kB
Feb 16 11:18:16 ip-172-31-100-71 kernel: [67744020.934420] init: mysql main process (14232) killed by KILL signal
```

Like I said before, my server is c3.xlarge with 8Gb RAM. Normal utilization is pretty low. I think there was a backup process that was running, maybe it could have caused higher resource utilization.

Any suggestions how to check further?

Comment: *I managed to repair it manually using:* Are you sure that the problematic table's engine is MyISAM?

Comment: I am checking the database in phpMyAdmin. Some of the tables are InnoDB, some are MyISAM. The specific table with the error is MyISAM.

Comment: This is likely caused by an abnormal termination of the MySQL daemon. Review the MySQL error log and the server syslog to identify why it happened.

Comment: I checked the mysql log. something about error 28 (updated in the question). From what I read it is disk space, which is weird because I have at least 2.5Gb free

Comment: MyISAM tables are easily get corrupted. Migrate to InnoDB.

Comment: It is an out of memory issue. I updated the question. I am checking what could have caused it. Any suggestion is welcomed

Answer (score 1):

"marked as crashed" -- Longterm solution:  Switch from MyISAM to InnoDB.

"errno 28" -- Check the setting for `tmpdir` and consider changing it to a bigger dis partition.

"Out of memory" -- What is running?  Is this server hosting MySQL only?  Or does it have other things, such as a web server and PHP?  If hosting multiple apps, let's see `my.cnf` so we can advise on what settings to shrink.

References:

- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory
- http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Comment: The server was running other php files, some of them were not quitting cleanly, consuming ram. Took a while to find, thanks.